# Displaying the username after login not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble displaying the username after login on my index page.

The code I have for Logging in:

```
protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            // Log the user into the site
            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
        }
        // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
        InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

Then in my Index Page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="WelcomeBackMessage">Label</asp:Label>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WelcomeBackMessage.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is that there are no errors and it is not displaying the name at all.

Thanks

Comment: Let us look at the lifecycle events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) | Load might be to early. The session ID used to identify the user is either part of the Form Variables or the Cookie being send along, and it might just not have been processed at that time. | SaveStateComplete sounds like the droid you should be looking for.

Comment: Use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`

Comment: this will only work if you are going to redirect the user to the default page. otherwise you need to follow my instructions below.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to actually login your user. All you do is validating the users credentials and then do a redirect. So try to add the following line in your if-statement:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
    {
        // Log the user into the site
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, true);
        // Do the redirect
        Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
    }
    // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
    InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
    {
        WelcomeBackMessage.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        // Log the user into the site
        Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");

Place WelcomeBackMessage label in master page and try this code.
```