# Being redirected back to login screen when using Authorization in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having some trouble trying to resolve this issue I am experiencing.  I have a folder named "Admin" and in that folder I have two web forms and the `web.config` file.  I have created the users and added them to their roles.

In the `web.config` file I have:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Administrators" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

When I login with administrator (who is in the Administrators Role) I get redirected to the Index page (this all works). However when browsing from there to the admin pages I get redirected to the Login screen, but I have added the role `Administrators` in my `web.config` file?

This is my login.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            Session["UserName"] = this.UserName.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
        }
        // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
        InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

Then in my root `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <!--Add a customized SqlMembershipProvider -->
    <add name="SqlProvider"
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
    enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
    applicationName="SecurityTutorials"
    requiresUniqueEmail="true"
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
    minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
    passwordAttemptWindow="10"
    passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" 
             defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             cacheRolesInCookie="true"
             createPersistentCookie="false"
             cookieProtection="All">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>

</roleManager>
```

And then in the Admin folder's two web forms I have the following:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserName"] != null)
            {
                this.WelcomeBackMessage.Text = string.Format("Welcome {0}", Session["UserName"].ToString());
            }
```

I am not sure what is going on here and need some assistance please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606263/5507748 you are not logging in your user. You only write a session variable here, so you need to login your user with the line `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, true);`. Then you can access the username by `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()`. There is no need for a session variable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it should be `Administrator`, singular...